# SQL / Access - Self Join Required to get most recent value?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a SQL query, which is based on the following tables:

```
Metric
----------
ID
Description

Desired_Future_State_Metric
----------
ID
Metric_ID
Desired_Future_State_ID
Target_Value
Target_Date

Metric_Value_Measurement
----------
ID
Metric_ID
Measurement_Date
Measurement_Value
```

The goal is to find the most recent `Measurement_Value` for each `Metric_ID` from `Metric_Value_Measurement` in order to show it in a table of `Desired_Future_State_Metric`. (Most recent measurement should be defined as the `Value_Measurement` with the most recent date, for each `Metric_ID`).

The following SQL (generated from an answer to another question) is the starting point, as it allows me to get all of the required data, including the most recent date; the only thing I can't do is join in the actual `Measurement_Value`.

```
SELECT Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
,Metric.Description
,Metric.Unit
,S.MaxDate 
FROM ((Metric
INNER JOIN Desired_Future_State_Metric 
ON Metric.ID = Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID)
INNER JOIN Metric_Unitvalue ON Metric.ID = Metric_Unitvalue.MetricID)
INNER JOIN (SELECT Metric_ID, Max(Measurement_Date) As MaxDate FROM
Metric_Value_Measurement GROUP BY Metric_ID) As S
ON Metric.ID = S.Metric_ID
ORDER BY Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
,Metric.Description
,Metric.Unit
,S.MaxDate;
```

In order to try getting the `ID` of the most recent measurement into the table I tried to change the subquery to:

```
(SELECT Metric_ID, Max(Measurement_Date) As MaxDate, MAX(ID) FROM
Metric_Value_Measurement GROUP BY Metric_ID)
```

My thinking was that this would give me the highest ID for the `MaxDate` (which I could then have used to get the `Measurement_Value`) but unfortunately the two columns are getting their max independently; as such, the ID is just the MAX of the ID column for that `Metric_ID`, not the max for that `Metric_ID` and date.

So, I'm at the point where it seems I will need to do a self join on that table in order to get the measurement, but each time I try to do this, I get the error (even though I'm using brackets round my join):

```
JOIN expression not supported
```

Is a self join the right way to go about this? Is there any other way to get the `Measurement_Value`?

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Comment: Rohan, The sample data would just be Numeric IDs and Dates, with some numbers for the values... not sure that would be helpful, or how I would post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the most recent measurement dates.

```
select metric_id, max(measurement_date) max_measurement_date
from metric_value_measurement
group by metric_id;
```

Join that to metric_value_measurement to get the entire row for the most recent measurement dates.

```
select t1.metric_id, t1.measurement_date, t1.measurement_value
from metric_value_measurement t1
inner join (select metric_id, max(measurement_date) maxdate
            from metric_value_measurement
            group by metric_id
           ) t2
        on t1.metric_id = t2.metric_id 
       and t1.measurement_date = t2.maxdate;
```

This is a useful query in itself. If I were you, I'd create a view from this SELECT statement, and use the view in your query. Microsoft Access's optimizer has a history of doing a good job of optimizing views used in joins. Let's say you name that view Most_Recent_Metric_Value_Measurement.

Then I *think* you can change this inner join . . .

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT Metric_ID, Max(Measurement_Date) As MaxDate FROM
Metric_Value_Measurement GROUP BY Metric_ID) As S
ON Metric.ID = S.Metric_ID
```

. . . to this . . .

```
INNER JOIN Most_Recent_Metric_Value_Measurement S
        ON Metric.ID = S.Metric_ID
```

The remaining bit is that you're using the column alias "maxdate" in the outer query. As I wrote it, the query above uses the original column name, "measurement_date", not "maxdate". (I think "measurement_date" makes more sense when you look at the view.) So you need to change "maxdate" to measurement_date in the outer query, or change the view to use the column alias "maxdate".